# Dompdf 0.8.3 not fetching remote CSS in PHP 7.2 and CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I'm upgrading my environment to PHP7.3 (from PHP5.5) and my DomPDF new installation (from 0.6 to 0.8.3) does not fetch any external CSS files. All server-related configuration seems ok, but only relative CSS files are loaded.

What may I be missing?

I'm using the following lines to generate the PDF:

```
require_once("dompdf_0-8-3/autoload.inc.php");

$options = new Dompdf\Options();
$options->set(array('isPhpEnabled'          => true, 
                    'isRemoteEnabled'       => true, 
                    'isJavascriptEnabled'   => false, 
                    'isHtml5ParserEnabled'  => true, 
                    'tempDir'               => sys_get_temp_dir())
        );

$dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf();
$dompdf->setOptions($options);    
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);    
$dompdf->setPaper($size, $orientation);            
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
```

Note: I'm using base_url() in link href's tag, inside the HTML view.

Anyone has the same problem or any suggestion on how to solve?

Comment: some more code would be very useful (mainly, a sample from the code in your view)

Comment: having said the above, I'd like to tell you my experience. I stopped using external CSS files and decided to inline the styles in the views I'll use for exporting with dompdf (using 0.8.3 as well) and saw massive (up to ten-fold) increases in generation speed. Perhaps you should consider that instead of wasting time using external CSS files :)

Comment: have you used `setHttpContext` ?

Comment: Just to keep you updated: The problem was solved in HTTP, it was a port redirection issue. HTTPS test is still pending :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a port redirection issue in the server. Solved :) Thank you all!